# Connect to samba server remotely

Tags: windows-7, linux, samba

I have a Samba server say at "abstergo.m12.in"

I'm fairly new to Samba as I usually use SFTP for file transfers but I wanted something more Windows Native.

I used the samba config from http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/305771-quick-and-dirty-samba-setup but changing the directory and the share name.

I'm trying to map the network drive. I try using //abstergo.m12.in/*sharename* but with no avail.

What I'm asking is how to setup the server (or client) so that I can connect to it remotely.

Edit:
For some clarification I'm trying to access it remotely. over the internets.

Comment: You kind of have to describe the problem. Just saying it didn't work isn't very helpful. Are you trying to access a Samba server over a WAN? If so, that's a terrible idea. The SMB protocol is only designed for file sharing over a LAN. (It can be used over a VPN, though performance tends to be awful.)

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: Windows uses backslashes in UNC paths.

Comment: Note that many ISPs block the Windows file sharing ports, so you're likely to have problems trying to do it that way.

Comment: @qmarchi: Just don't do that. It's the wrong tool for the job. Samba is a LAN thing, not a WAN thing. If you have no choice, you can get it to work over a VPN, but performance will be terrible. Whatever your outer problem is, there are better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @David noted this is not simple to use samba from wan. In local net [deamon swat](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/SWAT.html) provides the tools to confugure samba server over `http://localhost:901` but this is not directly accessible as wan web host. You rather look for webdav [WebDav DavenPort](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/) or ssh  with portforwarding use. [Found similiar question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/105241/accessing-samba-shares-over-the-internet)

Answer (score 1):

Setup Tinc VPN on both the machine and watch magic happend
http://www.tinc-vpn.org/

Tinc will create a virtual private network over wan (the internet)
and if you have a fast outbound bandwidth it will stream video/audio just fine, i have tried it a few times and it plays pretty reliably inside tinc tunnel (windows share)

Answer (score 0):

Using Samba/Windows file sharing over public networks is very insecure and inefficient. Don't do that.

If you want something more "windows native" - just use ftp support built in every Windows operating system. It's called "network locations".

Tutorial is here: [Work with files on an FTP site (microsoft.com)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/work-with-files-ftp-site#1TC=windows-7)

On server side - you can use Microsoft IIS FTP server which is built in Windows (XP, 7, 8).

Tutorial is here: [Set Up FTP in IIS 7 (microsoft.com)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771012(v=ws.10).aspx)

You can go even further and use free [FtpUSE tool](http://www.ferrobackup.com/ftpuse/). It is not built in windows, but allows you to map ftp locations like windows network drives and after you configure it - you see your ftp like disk. It may be helpful for scripting.